# Commit or download generated/uploaded files in heroku server

Tags: php, mysql, git, heroku

I'm using heroku's php/mysql server but currently having a problem about downloading the files on server.

The story is, I uploaded and installed a community forum software on the server, and as the installation proceeded, the software itself edited a config file, and later generated theme files.

And the problem is, that I can't find ways to access those files, because they were never really added or commited on git, thus even I clone the repository they are unaccessible.

How can I clone/merge these auto-generated(by the forum software) files?
Is there any way I can do it?